# to prompt/introduce a bill

Tags: verbs, vocabulary

What is the difference between "prompt" and "introduce" when the object is "bill," i.e., a piece of legislation?

> John prompted/introduced the bill in 2018.

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: Both are fine, but they mean different things. What are you trying to express?

Comment: If a person prompts a bill, does he support it after someone else introduces it?

Comment: Maybe, but not necessarily. It depends entirely on the situation—if the so-called prompting was conscious or deliberate and if the person wants to support it after the fact or not. But I don't see how that's a question about English.

Comment: Many people say "prompt" is wrong; they'd use "promote" or "sponsor."

Comment: (1) *My illness **prompted** my friends and family members to donate to research*. (2) *The climate crisis **prompted** senators to discuss an environmental bill.*

Comment: But the subject of my original example refers to a person, not an incident or situation.

Comment: And as some people pointed out, to prompt something is to initiate or trigger something. If someone has introduced a bill, how can others prompt it (assuming that people can prompt a bill)?

Comment: A person can still be the cause of something happening. I was only giving examples. But there is nothing redundant about this: *Jane prompted John to introduce a bill*. The two words have different meanings and cannot simply be swapped.

Comment: After someone has introduced a bill, can it be prompted by someone else?

Comment: No. Look at the definitions of the two words.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, an event or some new information [prompts](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/prompt) something, for example in this [Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/environment/2019/aug/22/microplastics-in-water-not-harmful-to-humans-says-who-report) article:

> This has prompted concerns that humans might be contaminated by the chemicals used in plastics or the pathogens that ride on the particles.

A person or organisation would [introduce](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/introduce) something, for example this [Lonely Planet](http://Australian%20carrier%20Tigerair%20has%20introduced%20a%20raft%20of%20new%20digital%20improvements) article:

> Australian carrier Tigerair has introduced a raft of new digital improvements

Answer (score 0):

> Prompted (Prompt)

This would be the initiator to start drafting the bill. (Something that happened that raised the idea that a bill was needed to get a law in place)

> Introduced (Introduction)

This would be tabling the bill/motion in parliament (or other legislative body) to get it passed into law.